# How to interpret this error when running stack build?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Here is what I did:

- Created fresh project by `stack new ...`
- Added `Spock` to `dependencies` in `package.yaml`

I ran `stack build`, but got an error advising me to add a dependency to `stack.yaml`, so I did

- Added this line to `extra-deps` in `stack.yaml`:

```
extra-deps:                                                                                                                                                                                - Spock-0.13.0.0@sha256:163ef2698fed8f5801428d8dbe794fd126415a5ff3304b227750fdc4037497be,3745
```

Ran `stack build` again, got this error:

```
Received ExitFailure 1 when running
Raw command: /home/agam/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-8.8.4/bin/ghc-pkg-8.8.4 --user --no-user-package-db --package-db /home/agam/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/3932a3bb22be25146410341fc169e381513f21d026d12cb649688c6644f5c69c/8.8.4/pkgdb dump --expand-pkgroot
Standard error:

ghc-pkg: /home/agam/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/3932a3bb22be25146410341fc169e381513f21d026d12cb649688c6644f5c69c/8.8.4/pkgdb/package.cache: GHC.PackageDb.readPackageDb: inappropriate type (not enough bytes)
```

I'm not sure how to interpret this error ... "*not enough bytes*" ?

**Update**: tried deleting `~/.stack`, didn't help:

```
➜ rm -rf ~/.stack
Preparing to install GHC (tinfo6) to an isolated location.
This will not interfere with any system-level installation.
Preparing to download ghc-tinfo6-8.8.4 ...
ghc-tinfo6-8.8.4: download has begun
ghc-tinfo6-8.8.4:    8.77 MiB / 198.61 MiB (  4.42%) downloaded...
ghc-tinfo6-8.8.4:   24.09 MiB / 198.61 MiB ( 12.13%) downloaded...
ghc-tinfo6-8.8.4:   39.31 MiB / 198.61 MiB ( 19.79%) downloaded...

...

ghc-tinfo6-8.8.4:  197.10 MiB / 198.61 MiB ( 99.24%) downloaded...
ghc-tinfo6-8.8.4:  198.61 MiB / 198.61 MiB (100.00%) downloaded...
Downloaded ghc-tinfo6-8.8.4.
Unpacking GHC into /home/agam/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-8.8.4.temp/ ...
Configuring GHC ...
Installing GHC ...
Installed GHC.

➜ stack build
Received ExitFailure 1 when running
Raw command: /home/agam/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-8.8.4/bin/ghc-pkg-8.8.4 --user --no-user-package-db --package-db /home/agam/code/simple-spock/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/3932a3bb22be25146410341fc169e381513f21d026d12cb649688c6644f5c69c/8.8.4/pkgdb dump --expand-pkgroot
Standard error:

ghc-pkg: /home/agam/code/simple-spock/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/3932a3bb22be25146410341fc169e381513f21d026d12cb649688c6644f5c69c/8.8.4/pkgdb/package.cache: GHC.PackageDb.readPackageDb: inappropriate type (not enough bytes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means your GHC package DB is corrupted somehow and it's time for a `rm -rf ~/.stack` + rebuild.

I've managed to corrupt it in the past by running multiple Stack operations at the same time but it's hard to say how you did it.

*Update to answer before accepting*:

1. `rm .stack-work`
2. `rm -rf ~/.stack`
3. `stack build`

Comment: Thanks! 

Tried that, didn't work (will update the question to include text snippet)

Comment: However, _also_ deleting `.stack-work` (local to the project)  _before_ deleting `~/.stack` worked.